# Form data erased after Windows form is closed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, .net-4.0

I have a subsidiary form where I can enter data and then save it before closing the form and going back to using the main form.
When I re-open the subsidiary form, I cannot see the changes in the data that I had entered earlier.
Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong ?

```
 MainForm.vb
    Public Class Maincls
    oTestObj as New Testcls
    oTestObj.XYZ = "XYZ"

    Private Sub SoftwareSettingsToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SoftwareSettingsToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Testcls.tbXYZ.Text = oTestObj.m_XYZ
    Testcls.Show()
    End Sub
    End Class


    Form_Testcls.vb
    Public Class Testcls

    Structure Params
    Dim m_XYZ as String
    End Structure
    Dim oParams as Params

    Public Sub New ()
    InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
    XYZ = tbXYZ.Text
    Me.Hide()
    End Sub

    Public Property XYZ() As String
            Get
                Return Me.oparams.m_XYZ
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me.oparams.m_XYZ = value
            End Set
       End Property
    End Class
```

Comment: You create a new instance of the form, like you should.  Yes, this new instance doesn't remember what the old one looked like.  You have to help.

Comment: Suppose I open Form Testcls and make changes and click OK button, Then I reopen form Testcls, the changes are not shown in the form
The object OTestcls in the method `SoftwareSettingsToolStripMenu_Click` does not contain the updated value of m_XYZ.

Can you tell me how to  update changes in the method SoftwareSettingsToolStripMenu_Click and feed them to the textbox ?

What point of time should I create another object and where should I do it ?

Thanks

Comment: The quick and dirty solution may be to change `Testcls.Show()` to `oTestObj.Show()` which will just re-display the same form. But you should create a new form and pass in the object containing the values to be displayed. When the form is closed, save the values to the object.

Answer (score 0):

I think in windows forms the work around for this is to create a static class and add properties according to your requirement. Then populate these static properties on closing of your form. Now you can use the value set in the static data members, unless otherwise you change them on any other event.

Edit: In vb.net the Static is actually `NonInheritable`